# How to put record number for each page next to pagination in ag-Grid angular?

Tags: angular, pagination, ag-grid, server-side, ag-grid-angular

Based on [customising pagination example](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-pagination/) in ag-Grid, I can set page size for my grid. how can I put page size component next to the page numbers at the below of grid?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to my knowledge, we can't customize the default pagination panel template,

I think you have two solutions:

**First:** developp your custom panel that include your needs by using [status bar panel](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/component-status-bar/) and by disactivating the default pagination panel with  `suppressPaginationPanel=true`

**Second:** use javascript to dynamically insert your component into the default pagination panel

hope that help

Comment: Thank you so much, it was too useful for me. But I'm curious about how to use javascript to dynamically insert my component into the default pagination panel?